# NSURL path doesn't understand a plus sign in a URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

As you know a plus sign in a URL translates to a space character.
[NSURL path] returns a path replacing all %xx with corresponding characters.
But it doesnt translate '+' to a space! It leaves it as a plus sign.
Is it a bug or what?
How can I use NSURL to work with URLs which contain spaces encoded as pluses?

thanks

Comment: This URL is sent to my app within an sms message. I tap on the sms and my app is launched and application:HandleOpenURL method is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Any equivalence between + and space happens on the server, not the client. If you want to translate plus signs to spaces in a client program (I assume you have a reason), you'll have to do that yourself—*before* unescaping the %xx escapes.

And you will do that on the NSString side, not the NSURL side.

Answer (score 0):

As the RFC 2396 (Uniform Resource Identifier) states

> Many URI include components
>   consisting of or delimited by, certain
>   special characters.  These characters
>   are called "reserved", since    their
>   usage within the URI component is
>   limited to their reserved    purpose. 
>   **If the data for a URI component would conflict with the    reserved
>   purpose, then the conflicting data
>   must be escaped before    forming the
>   URI.**
>
> ```
>   reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
>                 "$" | ","
> ```

So I think you have to escape the plus sign in your URL string before applying to NSURL.

Comment: Escaping the plus sign would do exactly that—preserve the plus sign as it is. The questioner wants to treat it as equivalent to a space.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is it a bug or what ?

A: no it's a feature and it would be a bug if it was translated to space because the plus is reserved for being interpreted as a space on *serverside*.

Q: How can I use NSURL to work with URLs which contain spaces encoded as pluses?

A: Leave them as they are. The server will do the rest.